# Calcular 2 números e exibir no segundo input

Tags: javascript

Ao realizar um cálculo de 2 `inputs` preciso que o resultado seja exibido no segundo `input`.

O resultado não pode aparecer no terceiro `input`, para realizar o próximo cálculo, o campo 02 não pode armazenar o valor total, terá que armazenar o valor digitado ou o valor da varíavel inicial.

Código:

```js
function myFunction01(){ 
  var p1 = document.getElementById('demo01').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('demo02').value;
  document.getElementById("demo02").value = myFunction(p1,p2);
} 

function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  return p1 * p2; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  Espessura
  <input type="text" value="1.5" id="demo01">
  
  Raio da Dobra
  <input type="text" value="2" id="demo02">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction01()">clique</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pode colocar seu seu código na pergunta mostrando o que já fez?

Comment: Como assim? O resultado do cálculo deve aparecer no segundo input mas ele não pode guardar o valor? Coloque tb um [mcve].

Comment: Que terceiro input? A ideia do próximo cálculo é a mesma do primeiro cálculo? Não entendi o objetivo.

Comment: O objetivo e manter sempre os valores inicias das variáves, por exemplo: 'raio1 = 6, eixo =2', 'raio1 = raio1 * eixo ', então o calculo do raio1 = 12, quero limpar esse resultado do raio1 e trazer de volta o valor da variável anterior, que é igual a 6, e também tem que aceitar valores digitado pelo teclado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Pelo que eu entendi o raio será sempre 2 mas o resultado deve ser exibido no input do raio, certo?!

Vou escrever uma solução em javascript puro, sem usar a biblioteca JQuery.

```js
function myFunction01() {
  let p1 = document.getElementById('demo01');
  let p2 = document.getElementById('demo02');
  const raio = 2;

  p2.value = myFunction(p1.value, p2.value);

  p1.addEventListener('click', function(){
      p2.value = raio;
  });
 
}

function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  return p1 * p2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <label for="demo01">Espessura</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" value="1.5" id="demo01">

  <br><br>

  <label for="demo02">Raio da Dobra</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" value="2" id="demo02">

  <br><br>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction01()">clique</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Victor, era isso que precisava.

Comment: De nada @ClodoaldoDias, fico feliz em ajudá-lo. Se for possível, marque a resposta como melhor resposta para fechar a pergunta. :)